# Extracting 2 values from different columns from a DB with only 1 Select

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

**Problem solved:** This is the solution, thanks to @dont-panic and everyone who helped me !

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $option .= '<option id="opcion" value="'.$row['nombre'].'">'
                    .$row['nombre']
              .'</option>';
    if (isset($_POST['postre']) && $row['nombre'] == $_POST['postre']) {
        $preciodelpostre = $row['precio'];
    }
} ?>
```

---

as the title say, I'm trying to make a very simple accounting website for my grocery store where I keep my daily sales registered. I already made a form to add new articles in the Database with these table names:

> Table: Postres -- postreID(id of the article), nombre(name of the
>   article), price(price of the article).

I also have another table called "ventas", which is where I wanna store all my sales based on a date criteria, which is already done.

> Table: Ventas -- id(sale id), fecha(date of registered sale),
>   postre_vendido(name of the article sold), ganancia(the article price).

This is my code to register my sales:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'db641973975.db.alansete.com';
$dbuser = 'dbo675';
$dbpass = 'dotCos215';
$dbname = 'db643975';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);
$get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Postres ORDER BY postreID ASC");
$option = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
    $option .= '<option id="opcion" value = "'.$row['nombre'].'">'.$row['nombre'].'</option>';
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $postrevendido = $_POST['postre'];
    $preciodelpostre = $_POST['precio'];
    if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Ventas (id,fecha,postre_vendido,ganancia) VALUES(NULL,NOW(),'$postrevendido','$preciodelpostre')";
        $retval = mysql_query($sql);

        if(! $retval ) {
            die('Could not enter data: <p></p><a href="ventasdiarias.php" target="_self">Agregar otro articulo</a>' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Postre agregado exitosamente!!" . "Volviendo..." . '<p></p><a href="ventasdiarias.php" target="_self">Agregar otro articulo</a>';            
        mysql_close($conn);

    }else {
        ?>
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <p>Producto Vendido 
            <select name="postre" id="postre"> 
                <?php
                echo $option . '<p></p>';

                ?>
            </select>
            <input name = "agregar" type = "submit" id = "agregar" 
            value = "Agregar Venta">
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php  }?>
</body>
</html>
```

At the end it only captures the first 3 columns from(id,fecha,postre_vendido,ganancia) and asigns column "ganancia" a value of 0.

You guys have any idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please replace your `db host,user,password` with some dummy text. Don't include real credential in the question. keep it a secret

Comment: Is the column `Id`  of table `Ventas` Auto_Increment ?

Comment: As a recommendation, the amount of spanish leads my to believe you should ask [here](http://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I think the answer is probably simply that `$_POST['precio'];` has 0 in it, or NULL in it, and since `ganancia` is a numeric field, that NULL is becoming 0 when inserted to the db.  Maybe you don't really have an `<input name='precio' />` in your form.

Comment: Maybe for instance, in your form you named it `<input name='preciodelpostre' />` but are trying to read with `$_POST['precio'];` You have to make the names match.

Comment: you can answer your own question (and accept this answer) if you found a solution. I would suggest you post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price isn't inserting because you don't have a control in your `<form>` that has the price in it, but I think the way to fix this is actually *not* to add such a control. In my opinion you really don't need or want the user to enter the price, you should read it from your product table at the time the form is posted. There are various ways to do that. One way is to set it as you are getting the options to show in the `<select>`.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $option .= '<option id="opcion" value="'.$row['postreID'].'">'
                    .$row['nombre']
              .'</option>';
    if (isset($_POST['postre']) && $row['postreID'] == $_POST['postre']) {
        $preciodelpostre = $row['price'];
    }
} ?>
```

If you do it this way, be sure to remove the `$preciodelpostre = $_POST['precio'];` later in the code; since there is not control named `'precio'` on the form, this will overwrite the previous value with `null` which will end up as `0` in your inserted row.

Comment: That is exaclty what I needed! Thank you so much you are my hero! I imagine because some of the words were in spanish you were a little confused, I just changed a few things I'll post an edit above if anyone finds it helpful.

Comment: It's not so much that I was confused by the Spanish; I really would suggest using ID rather than name as the value for the options (it tends to be more reliably unique, although name would be ok if your db has a unique index on it). Of course, that would require altering your Ventas table to reference the ID rather than the name of the article, but if ID is the primary key of Postres, it would make a better foreign key for Ventas. I should have stated that opinion in the answer rather than just changing the code.

Comment: And I just used the English "price" because that's what you showed in your definition of "Table: Postres".